# Running karma tests in headless Firefox browser not working on Jenkins

Tags: firefox, jenkins, karma-runner, opensuse, headless-browser

First time asking a question on SO. Please be kind. I will graciously accept question feedback.

I have a Jenkins instance running on an openSUSE Linux machine that I do not have root access to. I have configured Jenkins with a custom tool installation that pulls in Firefox 56.0.1 from `https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/56.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-56.0.1.tar.bz2`

I have an Angular app that's built on the Angular CLI. Here is the relevant section of my karma.conf.js:

```
browsers: ['FirefoxHeadless'],
singleRun: true,
customLaunchers: {
  'FirefoxHeadless': {
    base: 'Firefox',
    flags: [
      '-headless',
    ],
  }
```

My Jenkins has a job that pulls the Angular app and runs `ng test` using Firefox 56.0.1 with the `-headless` flag. However, it fails with the following feedback:

```
ERROR [launcher]: [39mCannot start Firefox

(process:3050): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 
'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Error: no display specified
```

Research into this error points to xvfb needing to be run for Selenium and a `DISPLAY` environment variable being set so that Firefox can connect to that display. Since this is supposed to be headless, I don't believe that xvfb should be required since running headless should not require a graphical display (I do not want to go through the work of trying to install xvfb on a machine I do not have root access to). Adding the `DISPLAY` environment variable only changes the error to `cannot open display: :10`.

How do I get my jenkins instance to run karma tests in a headless version of Firefox?

Comment: You may just need to install some additional libraries that firefox is linking against [See bug on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1372998)

Answer (score 4):

I came across your answer when searching for why `Firefox` as a browser did work on Windows but not on my non-GUI linux buildserver. Seeing that you named your custom browser launch config `FirefoxHeadless` made me remember I have heard of such a preset before:
The [Firefox launcher for Karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-firefox-launcher) supports a handful of ready-to-use launch configs 
which will launch Firefox with the right launch options:

```
Firefox
FirefoxHeadless
FirefoxDeveloper
FirefoxDeveloperHeadless
FirefoxAurora
FirefoxAuroraHeadless
FirefoxNightly
FirefoxNightlyHeadless
```

The package is available via [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-firefox-launcher). Using this might save you and others the hassle of additional launch configs.